# WCF, two endpoints on same listenUri casue AddressAlreadInUseException

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that exposes two netTcp-endpoints using same listenUri (same port number, same base address, say net.tcp://localhost:12345/myservice/ep1 and net.tcp://localhost:12345/myservice/ep2). Everything works fine until I change the *maxConnections*-settings in the binding configurations so that the first endpoint has *maxConnections* = 2 and the second *maxConnections* = 4. When I do so the runtime fails to start the service host throwing an **AddressAlreadyInUseException**. As long as the maxConnections-settings of the both endpoints are equal everything works fine (I can even set different timeouts and message size limits for the two endpoints).

Is it an expected WCF behavior/restriction that two endpoints listening on same port must have same maxConnections-setting? Unfortunately I didn't find anything on this topic in the msdn.

regards and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is expected behavior. I explained similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689008/wcf-maxconnections-property).